# Why doesn't UIButton.imageView setTintColor: work in IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I'm trying to change the color of UIButton image. In the viewDidLoad method I change the tint color to either the "appColor" or a grey color, that works fine. When the user taps the button, I try to change the tint color again but nothing happens. I even tried to change the image with UIButton.imageView setImage and nothing happens either. What am I doing wrong?

This works

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
     if ([checkActivityArray containsObject:[place objectId]]){
        [checkCount setTextColor:appColor];
        checkButton.imageView.image = [checkButton.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        [checkButton.imageView setTintColor:appColor];
    }
    else{
        [checkCount setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:170.0/255.0 green:170.0/255.0 blue:170.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
        checkButton.imageView.image = [checkButton.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        [checkButton.imageView setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:170.0/255.0 green:170.0/255.0 blue:170.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
    }
}
```

This doesn't

```
- (IBAction)checkMarkButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.enabled = NO;
    CheckMarkController *checkMark = [[CheckMarkController alloc]init];
    BOOL didComplete = NO;

    if ([checkActivityArray containsObject:[place objectId]]){
        didComplete = [checkMark removeCheckMark:place];
    }else{
        didComplete = [checkMark addCheckMark:place];
    }
    if (didComplete) {

        checkActivityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:checkMarkArrayFileName];

        int tempInt = [checkCount.text intValue];

        if ([checkActivityArray containsObject:[place objectId]]){
            [sender.imageView setImage:[checkButton.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]];
            [sender.imageView setTintColor:appColor];
            [checkCount setTextColor:appColor];
            tempInt++;
            checkCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tempInt];
        }
        else{
            sender.imageView.image = [sender.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [sender.imageView setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:170.0/255.0 green:170.0/255.0 blue:170.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
            [checkCount setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:170.0/255.0 green:170.0/255.0 blue:170.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
            tempInt--;
            checkCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tempInt];
        }
        sender.enabled = YES;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_26):

> To refresh subview rendering when this property changes, override the tintColorDidChange method.

And the `tintColorDidChange` method is defined here:

[UIView tintColorDidChange](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/tintColorDidChange)

> The system calls this method on a view when your code changes the value of the tintColor property on that view. In addition, the system calls this method on a subview that inherits a changed interaction tint color.
>
> In your implementation, refresh the view rendering as needed.

Comment: What would I need to put in tintColorDidChange?

Comment: Is the tintColorDidChange method called?

Comment: Try calling [super tintColorDidChange] before [self setNeedsDisplay]

Comment: Try [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: property "view" not found on object of type "UIButton"

Comment: Where exactly did you implement the tintColorDidChange method?

Comment: In the UIButton subclass